# PhpWord with CodeIgniter in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, phpword

I am trying to work with PhpWord over CodeIgniter but getting 'An uncaught Exception' with 'Message: Could not close zip file http://localhost/docprocess/uploads/MyFile.docx'

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and my uploads folder has 777 permission.

What I did is, Copy PhpWord folder in thirt_party folder and make an word.php in library with following code,

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once  APPPATH . '/third_party/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader as Autoloader;
Autoloader::register();

class Word extends Autoloader {

}
```

And my controller method is as follows,

```
public function document()  {
        $this->load->library('Word');
        //ini_set('sys_temp_dir', base_url() . 'uploads/tmp');

        // Template processor instance creation

        $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

        $section = $phpWord->addSection();
        $section->addTitle(htmlspecialchars('Welcome to PhpWord', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), 1);
        $section->addText(htmlspecialchars('Hello World!', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));

        // Saving the document as OOXML file...
        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        //print_r($phpWord);
        $objWriter->save( base_url() . 'uploads/MyFile.docx' );
    }
```

And I am getting this error,

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: PhpOffice\PhpWord\Exception\Exception

Message: Could not close zip file http://localhost/docprocess/uploads/MyFile.docx.

Filename: /home/tapan/www/docprocess/apps/third_party/PhpWord/Shared/ZipArchive.php

Line Number: 161
```

Please help me regarding this issue, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you check that you have good rights in the tmp folder that is used? Temp dir defined in php.ini is used if you haven't defined anything else... you can access the temp directory that PhpWord is using with Settings::getTempDir() (PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings)

Comment: Hi @ejuhjav
Thanks for your reply. I do check by getTempDir() its /tmp
I also tried to change the temp folder by using Settings::setTempDir() to a folder in the project with 777 permission. Still no luck :(

Comment: maybe you can debug it from the PhpWord code then - you probably have checked that the error is thrown in PhpWord/Shared/ZipArchive.php when zip object close method fails... i.e. you could try dumping getStatusString from the failing zip object and check whether that gives you any additional info

Comment: @ejuhjav Thanks again.
I find the fix. I used base_url() to uploads path which return URL for save file. Which cause the error. After using absolute path for save file I get it working. :)